# How To change value of button in form using Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a form like this:

```
<form action="#contact-form" method="post" class="th_contact-form" id="id-59907491">

<div class="form_line">
        <label for="widget-2-your-email" class="th-field-label email" style="display:none;">Your Email<span>(required)</span></label>
        <input type="text" name="widget-2-your-email" id="widget-2-your-email" placeholder="Your Email" class="email">
</div>
<div class="th_contact-submit">
        <input type="submit" value="submit" class="th_button">
</div>
```

I want to change the **value="submit"** to say **value="click here"**

How do I do that using javascript? I do not have the liberty of changing the form code as it is auto-generated via a theme in wordpress, and they don't have the option of changing the button text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fastest way: `document.querySelector("#id-59907491 [type=submit]").value = "click here";`

Most stable way:

```
var frm = document.getElementById('id-59907491'),
    inp = frm.getElementsByTagName('input'),
    l = inp.length, i;
for(i=0;i<l;i++) {
    if( inp[i].type == "submit") {
        inp[i].value = "click here";
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there is only one button with the `th_button` class:

```
window.onload = function () {

    var button = document.getElementsByClassName( 'th_button' )[0];
    button.value = "Click Here";

};
```

Comment: Unsupported in IE8 and below.